# Express-session and SQL: Can I use the info from connect-session-sequelize to feed a login/logout table?

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js, express-session

I have a small project which handles users' login/logout with express-session and connect-session-sequelize. It works as intended but I now I want to track the time users spend in the site.

At first I thought it would be just a matter of adding a record with user details to a login/logout table every time users successfully logged in and update that record when users logged out. That did not work as planned because sometimes users simply don't logout! They close the app or leave it running. In both cases, the next time they login a new record is added to the table and I am left with an incomplete record of their previous usage (i.e. no logout time).

Then I thought perhaps I could use the Sessions table created by 'connect-session-sequelize' to complete that information for me. I thought "If I add a trigger to the Sessions table which fires right before the session expires, I can update my login/logout table".

The problem is, to do so, I need a way to use the information in the 'data' field of the session record in the Sessions table, a text field for which contents look like this:

```
{
  "cookie:
  {
    "originalMaxAge":600000,
    "expires":"2021-03-08T02:02:02.002Z",
    "httpOnly":true,
    "path":"/"
  },
  "userOk":
  {
    "userEmail":"sample@hitmail.com",
    "loggedIn":true
  }
}
```

So, I guess my question is:

Is there a way to create a delete trigger which is able to extract the user e-mail from that record in the Sessions table and use it to locate and update the appropriate record in my login/logout table?

Alternatively, I could transform the session record and create the login/logout record when the session expires or the user logs out (since in both cases the record would be deleted from the Sessions table).

Or anything else you guys could suggest, really.

Any suggestions will be graciously accepted.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, MariaDB has Regex functions. Using REGEXP_SUBSTR I was able to create a "before delete" trigger which solved my problem.

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `updt_usage` BEFORE DELETE ON `eas_sessions` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE eas_usage SET logout = now() where user_email = REGEXP_SUBSTR(old.data,'([a-zA-Z0-9._-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)') and logout is null;
END
```